# How to Lazyload any src object in node body

Tags: theming, hooks, media

Currently using Blazy on Drupal 8. What I am trying to do is figure out how to lazyload any image, iframe, mp4 found in the body.

I think I have found a good solution as seen here:
https://www.drupal.org/project/blazy/issues/2912992

But how do I implement it. I am stuck at step 4.

Answer (score 1):

I think he means to add this to **mytheme.theme**

```
/**
 * Implements hook_page_attachments_alter()
 */

function MYTHEME_page_attachments_alter(array &$attachments) {
    $attachments['#attached']['library'][] = 'blazy/load';
}
```

Comment: This is how I am trying to get blazy to lazyload all images, but it is not working.

Apply lazyload / blazy to all images.

mytheme.ibraries.yml added the following dependencies:

blazy/load
In MYTHEME.info.yml added the following

libraries: - 'mytheme/global-styling' - 'mytheme/local'

In MYTHEME.theme Added the following:
/** * Implements hook_page_attachments_alter() */

function MYTHEME_page_attachments_alter(array &$attachments) { $attachments['#attached']['library'][] = 'blazy/load'; }


Currently getting this error: Fatal error: Cannot use assign-op operators

Comment: @Progonat have you tried to get it to work on fresh Drupal 8 install?